# populate combo box from database

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql, jsp

```
<select name="supplier">
    <%
        try {
        Connection conn = JavaConnect.ConnectDb();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs; 
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM supplier "); 

        while(rs.next()) {
            out.write("<option value ="+rs.getString("name")+"</option>");

        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        } 

        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.print("Sorry");
                           }
%>
</select>
```

I am trying to populate a combo box in a jsp page and have tried the above but im getting an empty combo box. I've researched other answers but  most of them don't seem to work.

Comment: You should be [avoiding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1037210) using Scriptlet from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you shouldn't be using java code in your JSP page. [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) is for that purpose. All this code should go into the server side. Check [SO Servlets Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) of the proper use.

But lets say your result set is returning something. So try this then:

```
out.write("<option value=" + rs.getString("name") + ">" + rs.getString("name") + "</option>");
```

If you'll see empty list again, then your result set is empty.

Comment: Thanks, result set is not empty, but how do i populate all values from database and not just 2.

Comment: It is up to you how to populate them :)

Comment: Like if i add more suppliers in the database, how would the above code change to take into account all

Comment: Why don't you try and see? Add more suppliers and see what happens. This `SELECT name FROM supplier` will select all the names from the database as many as there are records. So you will all names in your drop down.

Comment: Thanks just was confused as you had rs.getstring() twice